# Using underset and overset together

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I would like to use underset and overset together above and below the word. Current  output looks like this:

```
\begin{equation}
    v_t(j)=max^{N}_{i=1}v_{t-1}(i)a_{ij}b_j(o_t)
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I would like both the superset and the underset to be placed exactly above and below the *max*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!
As egreg pointed out in the comments, you can achieve what you want using `\max_{i=1}^{N}`, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Only for the equation* environment

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    v_t(j) = \max_{i=1}^{N}v_{t-1}(i)a_{ij}b_j(o_t)
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to use, and jupyter lab still rendered overset and underset symbols to the right of the sum symbol (in my case), so I had to use `\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}\sum}`

Comment: If you want to define a new operator, like `avg` you can use: \DeclareMathOperator*{\avg}{avg}. The asterisk (*) is needed for the subscript to work properly

Answer (score 7):

Here is maybe an easier fix yet - just nest overset in underset, or the other way around, as in:

```
v_t(j)=\overset{N}{ \underset{i=1}{max}} \hspace{0.1cm} v_{t-1}(i)a_{ij}b_j(o_t)
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure how this can be easier than `\max_{i=1}^N`

Comment: `\max_{i=1}^N` is not rendered the same in all libraries. In Katex, for instance, it could be rendered to the right. So this solution here works. – Note: The hack to render above and below constantly with Katex is to use: `\max \limits_{i=1}^N`